# How to transform my URI to have system date as well in MLCP

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

The uri is getting generated based on a unique key in my delimited input. But, for versioning of document to work , I require it to have system dateTime also. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can either provide a timestamp as part of the `-output_uri_prefix` or `-output_uri_suffix` arguments, or consider using an MLCP Transform for this.

See also: [Transforming Content During Ingestion](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518)

HTH!